# A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Tags: codeigniter-3

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Filename: datauser/editsuperadmin.php

Line Number: 20

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\mcicampus2\application\views\Superadmin\datauser\editsuperadmin.php
Line: 20
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\mcicampus2\application\controllers\Superadmin.php
Line: 107
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\mcicampus2\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: Your index doesn't exist in that array from the line 20.

Answer (score 0):

This error means the index doesn't exist in array. You should use isset before printing or using the value of the array.

To check whether the index exists or not you can use isset():

```php
isset($abc_array['xyz_data']) {
  echo $abc_array['xyz_data'];
}
```